# *ngFor para obtener la llave de firebase

Tags: ionic, angular, typescript

hola mi estructura de firebase es algo asi:

```
firebase
 contenedor1
          caja1
          caja2
 contenedor2
          caja1
 contenedor3
```

mi problema es como hacer para obtener los contenedores con ngFor lo que hago es esto

```
 <ion-select [(ngModel)]="numPed">
   <ion-option *ngFor="let item of pedidos" [value]="item.caja">{{ item }}</ion-option>
 </ion-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que quieres obtener el nombre del documento, puedes seguir [este ejemplo de la documentación de angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/7eb3e51022c7381dfc94ffb9e12555065f060639/docs/firestore/collections.md#example).

```
export interface Shirt { name: string; price: number; }
export interface ShirtId extends Shirt { id: string; }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let shirt of shirts | async">
        {{ shirt.name }} is {{ shirt.price }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  private shirtCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Shirt>;
  shirts: Observable<ShirtId[]>;
  constructor(private readonly afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.shirtCollection = afs.collection<Shirt>('shirts');
    // .snapshotChanges() returns a DocumentChangeAction[], which contains
    // a lot of information about "what happened" with each change. If you want to
    // get the data and the id use the map operator.
    this.shirts = this.shirtCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Shirt;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Donde creas dos interfaces de typescript, una que emula el json de tu documento y otro de que tiene una propiedad de tipo string llamada id.

Se creas una colección de firebase de tipo  y un observable de un array de Shirt.

Dentro del map vas llenando el observable (array de Shirt) y le añades la propiedad `id`. De esta manera podrías utilizarla dentro de un ngfor.

```
<li *ngFor="let shirt of shirts | async">
  {{ shirt.id }} is {{ shirt.price }}
</li>
```